# Nested Filter aggregation includes the null documents in the doc_count

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, aggregation

I have an elasticsearch index with following mapping :

```
{
"properties":{
    "asset":{
        "properties":{
            "customerId":{
                "type":"long"
            }
        }
    },
    "software":{
        "type": "nested",
        "properties":{
            "id":{
                "type":"long"
            },
         ... (more properties)
    }
}
```

}

There could be some documents which have `"software":null`
When a nested filter aggregation is performed on software attribute say, id, the doc_count in the filter aggregation includes those software too which are null.

aggregation looks like this :

```
"aggregations": {
    "aggs": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "software"
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "filtered": {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "software.type": {
                            "value": "Application",
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                },
                "aggregations": {
                    "software_ids": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "software.id",
                            "min_doc_count": 1,
                            "shard_min_doc_count": 0
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The part of the response :

```
"aggregations": {
    "aggs": {
        "doc_count": 129958,
        "filtered": {
            **"doc_count": 7094,**
```

This doc_count includes the "software":null
Is there a way to exclude them?

Edit : I have considered using "missing" param for the inner terms aggregations (i.e. for the aggregation inside the filter aggregation). But would like to know if there is any way to exclude such 'nested' nulls from the aggregations altogether.

Answer (score 2):

[Missing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_missing_value_14) attribute to the rescue.

With Missing attribute, you can specify what value the field should take if the field is missing. You can specify a value as "JUNK" and the document will then land up in JUNK bucket in your aggregation.

Following should work now.

```
    "aggregations": {
    "aggs": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "software"
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "filtered": {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "software.type": {
                            "value": "Application",
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                },
                "aggregations": {
                    "software_ids": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "software.id",
                            "min_doc_count": 1,
                            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                            "missing": "JUNK"
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah Should have mentioned earlier, missing attribute is one way to go about it. But wanted to know if there is any way to do this at the outer level aggregation.

Comment: Other way is to add another filter https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html for field software in addition to existing software.type. Hope this helps.

Comment: ohk, tried adding must_not exists in the filter. But it returns 0 doc_count.

Comment: why must_not ? It should be "must exist" as you want to exclude null fields from coming in aggregation count , isn't it ?

Comment: ohh yes, will try.

Comment: Added the filter. It did not have any effect on the doc_count.

Comment: For now, I have added an additional missing aggregation. What's better? Missing param or missing aggregation? Missing aggregation is parallel to other aggs. Using it, I can subtract its result from the filter agg doc_count.